# Rails how do I make rails go to an index page in a sub-directory without a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm using `rails 6.1.4` and `ruby 3.1`

I have a sub-directory inside my rails app, call it `/foo`

I've worked with rails some, but I've never done this. I want to create a landing page at `.../foo/index.html`.  Not for the entire app, just for when I go to the `...foo/` directory. I do not know how to do this or if it can be done.

I know rails normally needs a route, a controller, and a matching view. If if I create a controller, it changes the url to `.../foo/controller_name/index.html` and I don't want that. I would really like to just use `.../foo/index.html`.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Found a post about it after I posted here. Sigh!

https://gorails.com/blog/how-to-add-a-root-route-to-your-rails-app

It uses a main_controller inside the `.../foo` directory, and a matching view: `...foo/main/index.html.erb`.  It works without showing `main` in the url.  hmmm!